# issue with table having 2 foreign keys that lead to the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table, "Table A", that has two values ("user" and "assessor") that are used as identifiers for data in another table, "Table B". Within "Table B" any existing user is an assessor, they can assess others.

Because "user" and "assessor" link to the same table I can't perform a search on Table B if I wish to filter user and assessor at the same time, below is an example of what I mean:

```
select `tableA`.*
from `tableA` 
left join `tableB` on `tableA`.`user_id` = `tableB`.`id` 
left join `tableB` on `tableA`.`assessor_id` = `tableB`.`id` 
where LOWER(tableB.first_name) REGEXP "John" # user's name
    AND LOWER(tableB.first_name) REGEXP "Bill" # assessor's name
```

Is there are a quick way around this problem or will I have to create a separate table specifically for assessors, or clone existing table of users some how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are joining the same table for different mapping, use table alias to differentiate the joining table

```
SELECT `tableA`.* FROM `tableA` AS TA
LEFT JOIN `tableB` AS TB1 ON TB1.id = TA.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `tableB` AS TB2 ON TB2.id = TA.`assessor_id`
WHERE 
  LOWER(TB1.first_name) REGEXP "John" -- user's name
    AND 
  LOWER(TB2.first_name) REGEXP "Bill" -- assessor's name
```